# PHP expression output

Tags: php

I found somewhere in book

```
echo (int) ((0.1 + 0.7) * 10);
```

**output is : 7**

```
echo ((0.1 + 0.7) * 10);
```

**output : 8**

why both out are different ? I think answer should be  8

Answer (score 6):

When you write

```
echo ((0.1 + 0.7) * 10);
```

the result of this simple arithmetic
expression is stored internally as 7.999999 instead of 8.

Now when the value is converted to int,

```
 echo (int) ((0.1 + 0.7) * 10); // 7.999999 when typecasted to int becomes 7
```

PHP simply truncates away the fractional part, resulting in a rather
significant error (12.5%, to be exact).

Answer (score 2):

It's because float point at this scenario does not fit to memory and is truncated when converting to integer.

Read about that in [PHP manual about float](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

> Warning
>
> **Floating point precision**
>
> Floating point numbers have limited precision. Although it depends on the system, PHP typically uses the IEEE 754 double precision format, which will give a maximum relative error due to rounding in the order of 1.11e-16. Non elementary arithmetic operations may give larger errors, and, of course, error propagation must be considered when several operations are compounded.
>
> Additionally, rational numbers that are exactly representable as floating point **numbers in base 10, like 0.1 or 0.7, do not have an exact representation as floating point numbers in base 2**, which is used internally, no matter the size of the mantissa. Hence, they cannot be converted into their internal binary counterparts without a small loss of precision. This can lead to confusing results: for example, floor((0.1+0.7)*10) will usually return 7 instead of the expected 8, since the internal representation will be something like 7.9999999999999991118....
>
> So never trust floating number results to the last digit, and **do not compare floating point numbers directly for equality**. If higher precision is necessary, the arbitrary precision math functions and gmp functions are available.

Answer (score 0):

Please check  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php and find this

```
Warning : Never cast an unknown fraction to integer, as this can sometimes lead to unexpected results.
<?php
echo (int) ( (0.1+0.7) * 10 ); // echoes 7!
?>

See also the warning about float precision.
```